# JPA: Use String fields, but modify them and save as byte array

Tags: java, jpa

we are using JSON String in our application to store a lot of configuration data. Now we want to save this to a database as BLOB. The JSON String will be converted to a binary representation ([BSON](http://bsonspec.org/#/specification)) and then we want to store this.

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TBL_CONFIG")
public class ConfigEntity {

    [...]

    @Column(name = "CONFIG")
    @JSON
    private String config;

    [...]
}
```

Global EntityListener:

```
public class JsonBinaryConversionListener {

    @PrePersist
    public void process() {
        // Check @JSON fields and for every field
        [...]
       field.set(objectConversion.toBson(field.get()));
        [...]
        // The field is String, the conversion gives us a byte array
    }

}
```

The column CONFIG is set as BLOB. Only use the @Lob annotation wont work, because we want to change the value manually.

Is there a way that we can realize this through JPA?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using EclipseLink you can use a Converter,

see,
http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/a_converter.htm#CHDEHJEB

Otherwise you can use property access (get/set) methods to convert the data,

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Basic_Attributes#Conversion

The JPA 2.1 draft has also proposed Converter support.